# Redirect to another website with automatic login

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I have a asp.net web application that uses form-based login, let's call it 'A'.  I have another website that also uses login and password for users, let's call it 'B'. I have a scenario in which I want to open B from A and have the user automatically sign in to B. So if user is signed into A, I can get his login info and send it to B, so he doesn't have to sign in again. I checked and looks like it's poosible in Windows Form application using WebBrowser control. In asp.net If I use Response.Redirect then it takes me to login page, is it possible to send user name and password and sign into B automatically?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is a bit unclear. That being said, I think you may want to look into OAuth 2.0 to accomplish this. Be careful when sending credentials over the wire like that. OAuth 2.0 should tell you how to do this the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* send a username and password along with the `Response.Redirect`, but there is no out-of-the-box solution. 
Some websites offer Single-Sign-On procedures, I've seen it used in helpdesk applicationsto which you can redirect your users, and partly in AWS environments.

They usually receive a highly encrypted "token" in the QueryString which carries the credentials.